# que es mejor en php->number_format - foreach - price

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, foreach, integer

Tengo un foreach en una vista que recorre un array de registros de la bd en la cual hay un variable llamada "**price**",la cual debo pasa por un number_format en cada peticion 50 veces por el foreach

me preguntaba si quisas no es mejor guardar en la bd un $price_text

`$product->price_text='$'.number_format($product->price,2);`

y en el foreach solo mostrarlo y ya.

Estoy creando una web de un hotel ,asi que los precios aparecen casi en toda las vistas

**USO LARAVEL**

Comment: No tiene sentido guardar en una base de datos un campo que puede obtenerse directamente a partir de otro, es decir, el precio y el precio formateado. Siempre puedes obtener el precio formateado en la consulta que te recupera los datos y así no tendrías que aplicar una función en el código PHP del foreach.

Comment: puedo agregar un simbolo de moneda($), elegir entre coma o punto para separar los decimales con sql ? Mmmm no sabia eso.... ty

Comment: @RubioRic puedo estar deacuerdo contigo en este caso concreto. Pero aseverar que no tienen sentido guardar datos o campos calculados es pretencioso, existen casuísticas en el que es la mejor opción o incluso la única.

Comment: @xerif Los comentarios no permiten demasiada sutileza. No pretendía cubrir todas las casuísticas y las generalizaciones son muy malas ...

Answer (score 1):

No te recomiendo crear otro campo, sino crear un atributo que te devuelva el precio formateado.

Desde el archivo modelo `Product` vas a crear un método llamados en **Laravel** como **Accessor** con cualquier nombre relativo a lo que quieres, ejemplo:

Cómo crear el nombre del método: `get{NombreAtributo}Attribute()`

```php
Product extends Model {

    public function getFormatPriceAttribute() {
        return '$' . number_format( $this->price, 2 );
    }

}
```

En el foreach lo llamas de la siguiente manera:

```php
foreach( $products as $product ) {
    echo $product->formatPrice;
}
```

Te dejo el enlace de la documentación:
https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: Los accessor solo funcionarán si se está trabajando con modelos, si los objetos se traen desde el query builder no será posible aplicarlos.
Como alternativa al uso de query builder y suponiendo que el motor de BD siempre será el mismo, se puede formatear el numero con alguna función nativa del motor de base de datos y aplicarlo con [Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: lo que busco es **no** llamar a number_format 50 veces en cada peticion , hasta ahora lo que me funciono es guardar el array de Products en cache con cacheForever() con el precio ya formateado con `->trasform()` de los collection , como es data que no cambia mucho si puedo hacerlo, y entonces en cada peticion ni consulta debo hacer, nose si eso es mejor o peor pero asi ya no debo llamar a number_format mucha veces en cada peticion , en caso que los datos se modifiquen solo debo refrescar cahce y ya ,que tampoco sera muy frecuente

Comment: otra alternativa para mi es hacerlo con js, no formatear el precio en php y hacerlo con js, es decir en el html meter el precio en un div o en lo que sea y agregarle un `class="price_text"` luego agregar una funcion global js que busque esas classes y formatee lo que tenga adentro. Me desago de ese proseso en backend..... ,aunque si el usuario tiene internet malo , pasara lo mismo que cuando cargan las fuentes jajaja